# How to stream live events of one page to other page in laravel + socket.io?

Tags: laravel, socket.io

I have Implemented dice game in Laravel.
When user clicks on the "Roll Dice" button the dice rotates.
I want show same live dice on another page.

ScreenShot of dice :

[ScreenShot of dice pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCYaB.png)

Any help will save a lot of time for surfing.

Thanks.

Comment: i guess for this you can fire event of `Dice` position and show to other party via `websocket`

Comment: Hi, @KamleshPaul Okay. Would you please share some demo links if you have?
So, It could be helpful for me to understand.
Thanks :)

Comment: sorry i don't have demo but you need to search on socket.id emit and listening then you can use this

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use Laravel Echo and Socket.io.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d/

Make sure that your socket version is 2.3 any higher and it fails.

Comment: Hey @Michael Mano,

Thank you for your answer :)

But, I do not need to use laravel Echo because of need to implement this functionality in backend.

Is it possible to stream using nodejs as backend?

If yes, Would you please share any demo links with me?

Comment: I know this was awhile ago, But laravel echo is nodejs... https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-echo